# Postgresql Golang Martini Inserting key

Tags: postgresql, go, parameters, martini

I am working on building a social network type server as an exercise using martini, golang, and postgresql to help develop my skills in all three. The few key things that are eluding me are how to insert the primary key from the user table into the correct row of the user info table (to connect the user info with the specific user). I'm sure there is also a way to consolidate both the queries into a much more concise postgres script...

```
func CreateUser(ren render.Render, r *http.Request, db *sql.DB) {

  _, err := db.Query("INSERT INTO users (first, last, email, password, karma, value) SELECT  CAST ($3 AS VARCHAR), $1, $2, $4, $5, $6 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $3)",
    r.FormValue("first"),
    r.FormValue("last"),
    r.FormValue("email"),
    r.FormValue("password"),
    0,
    0)

  PanicIf(err)

  _, err = db.Query("INSERT INTO userinfo (usr, dob, phonenum, bio, mates, bought, sold) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)",
        0,
        r.FormValue("dob"),
        r.FormValue("phonenum"),
        r.FormValue("bio"),
        0,
        0,
        0)

  PanicIf(err)

  ren.Redirect("/")
}
```

Here is the script for creating the user table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "public"."users";
CREATE TABLE "public"."users" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL,
    "first" varchar(40) NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
    "last" varchar(40) NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
    "email" varchar(40) NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
    "password" varchar(40) NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
    "karma" int NOT NULL,
    "value" int NOT NULL
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
```

I realize that in production level code I would not want to store the password like this. I have also sort of been stumped by how to pull non-global parameters into the database as its is created by m.get & m.post commands.

```
 m.Post("/newuser", CreateUser)
 m.Get("/user", NewUser)
```

Any advice on consolidating and adding the key from users to the appropriate entry in userinfo would be greatly appreciated... I realize that these are probably incredibly stupid questions but please pardon my naivety.

Comment: So thanks to AlexAtNet i've been able to work around the initial question... Does anyone have any advice on consolidating the statements? Or eliminating superfluous code?

Answer (score 0):

I did it by returning the inserted user id from the first query and use it in the second one, but I did not use upsert.

So you can try use [RETURNING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-insert.html) to return the id of newly added user or query it separately by the email (as it looks like the email is unique per user in this case).

Then use it for second query:

```
_, err = db.Query(`INSERT INTO userinfo (usr, dob, phonenum, bio, mates, bought, sold)
                   VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)`,
    id, // there
    r.FormValue("dob"),
    r.FormValue("phonenum"),
    ...
```

I suppose that `usr` is the user id (foreign key to `users.id`)

Sample source code:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=alex dbname=tmp sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    rows, err := db.Query(`
        INSERT INTO users (first, last, email, password, karma, value)
        SELECT  CAST ($3 AS VARCHAR), $1, $2, $4, $5, $6
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $3)
        RETURNING id`,
        "first", "last", "email", "password", 0, 0)
    defer rows.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if rows.Next() {
        id := 0
        rows.Scan(&id)
        _, err = db.Exec(`INSERT INTO userinfo (user_id, info) VALUES ($1, $2)`, id, "info")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Println("Inserted:", id)
    }

}
```

I personally prefer QueryRow instead of query as it a bit more obvious that one row is returned, but it will work with Query as well.

Also I recommend to use unique index for email, instead of subquery.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm fiddling with it now... I'm still a little confused on how to make it work...      id, err := db.Query("INSERT INTO users (first, last, email, password, karma, value) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING id",                         triggers                                                    sql: converting Exec argument #0's type: unsupported type sql.Rows, a struct

Comment: To reiterate, I am struggeling with how to access the returned id... Where is the value from 'RETURNING id' placed?

Comment: I got it working by switching the top query to a queryrow and adding a .Scan(&id) to the end. I'd love to see a solution that involved a query instead of a query row.